# Counting pair of ordered subsets

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Tried using basic manual counting, not able to proceed

Comment: Please show us what you tried rather than telling us that you tried something.  Ask yourself this question:  If you add two integers and obtain an even integer, what must be true about the integers you added?

Comment: they must be even or they must be odd

Comment: While at least spend some time typeset the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The condition cannot be satisfied if $A$ contains numbers of distinct parity.

The same is true for $B$.

Comment: so ans will be 18?

Comment: That is correct.